# Set maximum value of NSInteger

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, max, nsinteger

**Sorry if this has been posted before but I have been looking for 30 mins now and cant find anything**

Hi, I have an NSInteger called currentcoins and I want the coins maximum value to be 999. I have tried everything including

```
#undef NSIntegerMax
#define NSIntegerMax 999
```

but the NSInteger isn't taking any notice of this.
Has anyone got any solutions? (I'm doing this for iOS)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never ever redefine a system define like `NSIntegerMax`.
This is set by the type of system you are building your app for (32 or 64 bit).

Just define your own max like:

```
#define kMaxCoins 999
```

Comment: I've defined this but the NSInteger is still going above 999

Comment: Oh, I haven't got a check in. Sorry I'm a bit thick somethimes

Comment: Ok `if (currentcoins < 90) {
        currentcoins = currentcoins + 1;
    }` I have 90 for testing purposes